# Why take the complex conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers

If I have the equation:

$$\frac{250+0.915j}{350+0.915j}$$

Why do I have to take the complex conjugate to rid of the complex part on the bottom?

Why can't I just times by:

$$ \frac{250+0.915j}{350+0.915j} \frac{-j}{-j}$$

Comment: Assuming that $j$ should be an $i$, then multiplying by $-i$ won't suffice because then you will introduce an $-350i$ term.

Comment: @Grid $j$ is sometimes used instead of $i$ - for example in physics the letter $i$ gets used for other things.

Comment: @MarkBennet Ah, thanks for letting me know. I've always seen exclusively $i$ in mathematics, but I guess it doesn't matter what you decide to call the imaginary unit.

Comment: I originally learned it as $j$.

Comment: I see $j$ every so often, but we never used it in any of my physics classes--always $i$ (for instance when writing general oscillatory solutions or time dependent wave functions).  Obviously that doesn't mean some colleges/physicists don't use $j$ but I don't think it's all that a common.

Comment: I've used it when $i$ was used for the instantaneous AC current...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because then you get $$\frac {-250j+0.915}{-350j+0.915}$$ and you still don't have a real number in the denominator.

The conjugate method depends on the fact that $(a+jb)(a-jb)=a^2+b^2$ is a non-zero (positive) real number unless $a=b=0$.